# Javascript how to upload a mp3 file from a link

Tags: javascript, form-data

I'm wanting to get the contents of a mp3 file from a url `get_mp3_file(mp3_file)`, then upload the contents of the mp3 I just downloaded, to another webserver and get the response.

```
var mp3_url = 'https://example.com/song.mp3';

function get_mp3_file(mp3_url) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', mp3_url, false);
    xhr.send();
    return xhr.responseText;
}

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file", get_mp3_file(mp3_url));

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://mp3-to-wav.com/upload-file.php', false);
xhr.send(fd);
var wav_link = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).link;
```

Comment: are you trying to do this in the browser or from a node application? if the former, this will not work, because your browser cannot access the downloaded file (also likely XSS restrictions, depending on where this is run exactly). If a node application, you'll want to combine https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html and https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch to get this result. An easier approach might be to have the browser send the url as a text string, and then have your PHP application independently download the file with curl or guzzle.

Comment: @MattKorostoff Through the browser. What do you mean it cannot access the file?

Comment: Also, I'm not trying to write the MP3 file to disk. I'm trying to get the MP3 file's content and upload them to a different webserver.

Comment: To prevent malicious content on a website, all browsers prohibit sending requests to another domain unless the target server specifically allows it. See [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for more details. You will need a backend server to "proxy" your request to your targeted website, as server side code is not restricted by CORS.

Answer (score 0):

the key was the File class. here's more about it.
https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#file-constructor

The solution for retrieving the contents of a file from one webserver, and then uploading it to another webserver:

```
var mp3_url = 'https://example.com/song.mp3';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', mp3_url, false);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function() {
    var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var file = new File([xhr.response], 'song.mp3', {type: 'audio/mp3'});
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    

    xhr2.open('POST', "https://convert-mp3-to-wav.com", false);
    xhr2.send(formData);

}

xhr.send();
```